# Order By Descending using String and Int in SQL

Tags: mysql

I Have try to display my testing column data is descending order using sql query but I accept data in following format

```
21
17
4
AB
0
AB
0 
AB
```

but I Want below format

```
21
17
4
0
0
AB
AB 
AB
```

I Want All AB value last of column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
ORDER BY col+0 DESC, col
```

Comment: it is Working but All AB Value not display in column and it will give Warning like Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect Double value: 'AB'

Comment: Ignore it `;-)`

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil *All AB Value not display in column* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efd813229cdedf2d3cdfad463a0bb636

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
ORDER BY
    col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' DESC,
    CASE WHEN col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN LPAD(col, 6, '0') ELSE col END DESC;
```

The first level of sorting places number strings before anything containing non digits.  The second level sorts descending by the column.  Note that we left pad with zeroes in the case the value be a number string.  This ensures that a lexicographical sort will agree with a numeric sort.

Comment: it is Working but All AB Value not display in column and it will give Warning like  Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'AB'

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

WIth Union:

SELECT * FROM documentsets WHERE tabla REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
UNION
SELECT * FROM documentsets WHERE NOT tabla REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'

Comment: UNION does not guarantee that separate blocks will stay in the obtaining order. In practice - the ordering stays unchanged until the intermediate rowset is cached to the disk.